# Space after html5's video tag

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have a html5's video tag, it seems that there is a `5px space` between video and its container div element.

If I put `font-size: 0` in the container element (`#video-container`), the space disappears.

I know this is a problem of `display: inline-block`, but I have no elements with that.

Also, trying the solutions of opening tags next the previous closing, didn't delete the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/g9t71mg6/

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#video-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2c5894;
}

#video-container video {
  width: 100%;
}

#turnera-container {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.turno-wrapper {
  height: 25%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.turno-wrapper {
  background: #727867;
}

.turno {
  border: dashed 1px #FFFFFF;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.turno .numero {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}

.turno .box {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}

#contenido-principal {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  /*margin-right: 250px;*/
}

#footer {
  background-color: #dc001e;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: dashed 1px #FFFFFF;
}

#rss-container {
  height: 240px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.turno-asignado-historia0 {
  background: #00bc24;
}

.turno-asignado-historia0 .numero {
  font-size: 65px;
}

.turno-asignado-historia0 .box {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.turno-asignado-historia1 {
  background: #739461;
}

.turno-asignado-historia2 {
  background: #546947;
}

.turno-asignado-historia3 {
  background: #34422e;
}

<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="turnera-container">
            <div class="turno-wrapper turno-asignado-historia0">
                <div class="turno">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="turno-wrapper turno-asignado-historia1">
                <div class="turno">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="turno-wrapper turno-asignado-historia2">
                <div class="turno">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="turno-wrapper turno-asignado-historia3">
                <div class="turno">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contenido-principal">
            <div id="video-container">
                <video autoplay loop="loop">
                  <source src="http://awakenvideo.org/video/UFOs/NVofu001.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="rss-container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just add `display: block` to the `video` element. `video` elements default to `display: inline`, causing the whitespace.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9t71mg6/1/

Comment: Spent a good time in inspecting elements in the GC Developer Console.  It was annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It is also worth noting that the reason for the so called "space" **below or above** in some [inline video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Styling_with_CSS) is because of the `line-height` that is defined on the container. So setting `line-height: 0` on the container of the video tag would also remove the space

Comment: Thanks, spent like 2 hours checking all the possible paddings and here we are.

Answer (score 3):

for your video is fullscreen (height and width 100%), use propertie css:

```
object-fit: cover;
```