# HTML <video> element causing space between it and next element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a video that is the background of the page. The video is exactly where it needs to be but is causing a huge gap between it and the next element. When I inspect the element there is no margin or padding, just the video which is the correct size. I am not sure where the gap is coming from or how to remove it.

```
<video loop muted autoplay class="bg-video">
  <source src="/assets/images/test.MP4" type="video/webm">
</video>
<h2 class="text-center">NEWS</h2>
```

That is the HTML. Nothing there but the video and the next element, which is an h2.

CSS:

```
.bg-video {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -100;
 overflow: hidden;     
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[screenshot of the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9IZY.png) (screenshot has been resized)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using left: 50% and transform: translate(-50%, -50%)?

If you remove those 2 rules, the space is eliminated and the video will fall back into it's natural flow in the page.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979003/space-after-html5s-video-tag

Comment: it's caused by your transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: Thank you. I now see exactly what the problem was. Space was there because it was allocated for the video, but since I used transform the video was moved out of that space yet it remains.

Answer (score 0):

you could try switching your position to fixed instead of relative, this takes it out of the flow of elements and it shouldn't be able to affect any others. i did a similar thing and the css was this:

```
#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
}
```